# Local database to be used by multiple applications/machines?

Tags: c#, php, wpf, database, offline

I'm looking for a local (offline) database solution. A database that does not run as a service nor needs to be installed. I came across SQL Server Compact, which seemed promising, except that it only allows multiple connections from same device/machine. This is a WPF project being written on C#. This application will run on computers that do not have access to the internet. It needs to have a database that is to be shared with other instances of the same application on the local network.

I considered writing on HTML/PHP but came across the same issue. I thought about using a portable apache server (which would have mysql) like usbwebserver V8, but really wanted to stay away from depending on running an application or risking to have compatibility issues.

Maybe there's no way to achieve this. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at SQLLite? I'm not sure what you have against an application running; if it needs to be accessible via multiple computers, that's much safer than granting access to the file system.

Comment: So, if a database isn't running as service - that means it's a program, that you (in Windows jargon) - doubleclick and VOILA. It works. How is that better than having a SERVICE that runs by disabling a silly user from closing it? Also, Apache cannot run MySQL. The reason it can't is the same why a 1.44MB floppy drive can't turn your copper ADSL into optical one. It makes no sense.  What you need to understand is that every database is "offline". They listen on a network interface and accept queries. Network interface can be a local intranet IP.

Comment: you can use MySql : free, efficient, 0 Restrictions... and can run as a simple executable. You can also use your c# code to connect to mysql instead of SQL Server